# Django self referential m2m field causes causes missing attribtue error

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I get an error if I try to make a self-referential m2m Field. Am I missing something here?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers')
```

somewhere else in a serializer:

```
def get_followers(user):
    return user.profile.followers

AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'followers'
```

Is there another way I can implement followers? Maybe I should make another model to do this or use a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Django treats all `self` m2m relations as symmetrical, for example if I am your friend, you are my friend too. When relation is symmetrical, Django won't create reverse relation attribute to your model.

If you want to define non-symmetrical relation, set `symmetrical=False` attribute on your field, example:

```
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False)
```

More on that in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)